# Field not allowing loupe. gvnix 2.0.0.M1

Tags: gvnix, gvnix-es

We have two child classes: Child1,Child2 that inherits from the same a class ParentClass, and only the class ParentClass.
We have a class A that contains a field parentList of type set field. This parentList is a list of ParentClass instances Ids

```
private Set parentList = new HashSet();
```

What we really want to achieve, is to select multiple values from either Child1 and Child2, and assign them to the parentList set field in class A, using Loupe.
When we try to execute the loupe command over the parentList field of class A, we get the following error:

**Field 'parentList' could not implement Loupe Field.**

What are the restrictions on the fields to use Loupe?
Is what we want to achieve, possible?

Answer (score 0):

This UI component is designed to handle relations between JPA Entities of type *many-to-one* in the *many* side of relation (field must be annotated with `@ManyToOne`).

Currently gvNIX doesn't include any component which handle `@*ToMany` relations the way you required. The most similar is the use of *master-detail* datatables (see `web mvc datatables details add` command). An example of this could be: master Vets and details Visits (selecting a Vet related Visits will be shown in *details* list).

The component you need can be done but you must create it by hand.

Good luck!